# How To Redirect IP Range To Different Address?

Tags: apache, httpserver

**I would like to redirect visitors from a defined IP range to a different location.**

For example, I want clients from this IP range 85.204.0.0/16 to be redirected to clientsA.html and clients from this IP range 195.178.124.0/23 to be redirected to clientsB.html

I suppose .htaccess is involved, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^85\.204\.$ [OR]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ clientsA.html [R,L]

 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^95\.178\.124\.$ [OR]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ clientsB.html [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

This will turn ANY page into the clients-page. You might want to change the `^(.*)$` part to (for example) `clients.html` -> that way only the client-page gets rewritten based on the IP address.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. I had to replace F with R (F gave me a 403 error. I suppose R means Read and L means List, what would F mean?

Comment: Oh, sorry :) F is Forbidden, meant to cause the 403 error. A case of bad copy-paste. Edited the answer to be correct.